# Can't find maxPwdAge in AD LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2016

I need to use the field "maxPwdAge" but I can't find out where it is.

I can read pwdLastSet without problems, but that field it's missing.

According to this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676863(v=vs.85).aspx

the field it's available up to 2012 version, but it's missing in 2016 version? or it's a lack of documentation update?

I've created a VM which runs a trial version of MS Server 2016 and can't find the field there either (nor in my production AD Server)

Any hint of because this field is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an attribute of the domain. You need to correct your query.

Comment: Correct it how?

Comment: Just found it, you're right. Now I have to figure out how to obtain it. I'm using spring boot